# Is there any other way of finding determinant of a matrix in C Programming Language

Tags: c

I tried to find it online but every solution is long like this one.
Is there any way to write it with for loop ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

 int a[3][3], i, j;

 long determinant;
 printf("Enter the 9 elements of matrix: ");
 for(i = 0 ;i < 3;i++)
     for(j = 0;j < 3;j++)
          scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

 printf("\nThe matrix is\n");
 for(i = 0;i < 3; i++){
     printf("\n");
     for(j = 0;j < 3; j++)
          printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
 }

 determinant = a[0][0] * ((a[1][1]*a[2][2]) - (a[2][1]*a[1][2])) -a[0][1] * (a[1][0]
  * a[2][2] - a[2][0] * a[1][2]) + a[0][2] * (a[1][0] * a[2][1] - a[2][0] * a[1][1]);

 printf("\nDeterminant of 3X3 matrix: %ld", determinant);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By recursion? If you search for "stackoverflow C determinant of matrix with recursion" you'll find several previous questions.

Comment: Finding the determinant of an nxn matrix is a fundamentally recursive procedure which is difficult to do efficiently with a for loop. For 3x3 matrices the above equation is probably as simple as you are going to get.

Comment: Aside: please get used to putting the newline at the *end* of your output, not the beginning. Sooner or later you'll be asking "why did this line not get printed?"